# Renaming redundant IDs sequentially

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rename

Not sure if there's an answer for this, but I'm in a situation where I have a set of idential elements, each having a sequential ID, like `id="thiselement1"`, `id="thiselement2"`, `id="thiselement3"` etc...

Is there a fast way for me to copy and paste one element 100 times and then give each a sequential identifier as shown above? Trying to save manually typing numbers over and over again.